# How to add new child with value in existing XML file in C# using DOM

Tags: c#, xml

I have already an XML file whose structure is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<configuration>
  <FilePath>C:\Recordings</FilePath>
  <Timer>2</Timer>
</configuration>
```

I want to to add one more child in `<configuration>` and want the new structure like shown below. Moreover, before adding I also want to make sure that the new child added is present or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<configuration>
  <FilePath>C:\Recordings</FilePath>
  <Timer>2</Timer>
  <LastSyncTime>Some Value</LastSyncTime>
</configuration>
```

If `<LastSyncTime>` is not there, then and only it should be added otherwise not.

I have tried so far as given below:

```
try
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(newpath);
    XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("LastSyncDateTime");


    if(nodes.Count == 0)    //Means LastSyncDateTime node does not exist
    {
        XmlNode mynode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Text, "LastSyncDateTime",null);
        mynode.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString() + "";
        doc.AppendChild(mynode);
    }
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.LastChild != null)
        {
            LastSyncDateTime = (node.LastChild.InnerText);
            Console.WriteLine("Last Date Time is : " + LastSyncDateTime);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //throw ex;
    string str = (String.Format("{0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

But I am getting exception. Please suggest me best working solution for this.
Thanks

EDIT : I am getting the following exception:

> `[System.InvalidOperationException] = {"The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should've used `XmlNodeType.Element` instead of `XmlNodeType.Text`. And it needs some other fixes as shown below :

```
.....
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//LastSyncDateTime");
if (nodes.Count == 0)    //Means LastSyncDateTime node does not exist
{
    XmlNode mynode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "LastSyncDateTime", null);
    //set InnerText instead of Value
    mynode.InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    //append to root node (DocumentElement)
    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(mynode);
}
.....
```

Comment: I tried in this way, but still XML is not modified... It's not giving exception also :(

Comment: Save `doc` back to file after modification completed : `doc.Save(newpath);`

Comment: That did the trick.. Thank you so much. But after saving, when I am trying to get value of LastSyncDateTime using `for each` loop, at that time I am still getting count == 0. How can I retrieve the value of LastSyncDateTime?

Comment: I think still there is a glitch. When I executed the above program second time, it again adds the `<LastSyncDateTime>` node in the xml file. Which is what I don't need it to be.. Any ideas?

Comment: use `doc.SelectNodes("//LastSyncDateTime");` instead of `doc.SelectNodes("LastSyncDateTime");`